# Reading AVCHD/M2TS files

Tags: video

I have a Sony Camcorder which records AVCHD discs that contains M2TS.
How can these files be read under Ubuntu?

A fresh installation of 10.10 will open the files but the playback is very choppy. The same thing goes when trying to add with OpenShot.

I found the following post which suggests to repackage with ffmpeg to an MKV file, which in my situation did not help:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1627194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in this post. Which is indeed about the requirements of the computer in order to be able to play high definition video without a hassle. Several answers for this question may give you a clue on where to start.

[Smooth fullscreen 1080p playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28078/smooth-fullscreen-1080p-playback)

Additionally, transcoding seems to be the choice for playing/editing these high definition videos. Check the information on the next link, which may help you to see how you can have your beloved memories into good quality videos (even for the net).

[How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files)

There are several questions and answers in this site which may help you to find the best and easiest way to transcode your videos.

Some friends and I are trying to find a way to have the best tools for video playback/edition, which is fully documented in this forum: [Israel Remix Team](http://ultimateeditionisrael.freeforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=618) May be you wish to take a look on it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, it seems that HD movie handling it quite resource intensive. As you said transcoding looks to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question so that maybe others can benefit.
Transcoding AVCHD files to MP4 with ffmpeg seems the easiest way to playback videos and use in video editing tools such as OpenShot.
I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -i inputfile.m2ts -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 192k -ac 6 -vcodec mpeg4 -aspect 16:9 -b 17000k -deinterlace outputfile.mp4;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a good article for reference:

http://lydia622520.tumblr.com/post/55761773800/smoothly-editing-sony-a57-a65-a77-60p-avchd-in-imovie

Although, AVCHD has been around for several years, 1080 60p/50p AVCHD files still cannot be fully supported well in iMovie, including iMovie 11. If you are recording AVCHD in 60i then iMovie 11 can do it fine. If however you are using 60p you must first "repackage" 60p AVCHD into iMovie format it can understand.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) (there is also a SNAP), or another modern video editing software.

> It's capable of playing and converting the .m(2)ts files inside your
> AVCHD.