# How can I record Skype video calls?

Tags: software-recommendation, skype, webcam, video-recording

According to [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=939048&page=3) I can't use xvidcap, VLC or screencast apps like kazam.

So, how can I record Skype video calls?

Answer (score 2):

There are several screen recording tools that will allow you to record a window (with audio), a portion of the screen or the whole screen, which includes but not limits to:

### **[Istanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul)**

[image]
[image]

### [gtk-recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

[image]

[image]

And there are probably lots of more useful tools. But this is what I have tested and does the trick for me. They are also probably in the repositories by default but I can't say that for sure.

Good luck!

Comment: which one offers the best in terms of a/v quality? above 2 or kazam or?

Comment: I haven't tested kazam, but those I have tested as in my answer are making excellent quality videos. An example for download only: http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/resources/desktop.ogv (59MB, right click, save target as) In VLC, Menu "Media" and "Open Network Stream", enter the url and click "Play". The full thread of this video source is placed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28078/smooth-fullscreen-1080p-playback/28090#28090. I am using Ogg Vorbis codec which can be changed easily as seen here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532

Comment: thz!i'm gonna try kazam now! so there is no dedicated app to record video calls for ubuntu?

Comment: For skype? not as fas as I can say. But if you find something, please inform. :)

Comment: hmm..thx for ur help :)

Comment: But will any of these tools record the audio from both sides?