# How do I transfer videos from a Kodak Playsport video camera to my computer?

Tags: 11.04, video

I tried downloading a clip from my Playsport video camera to my computer and could not get it to work. It was about a 15 second clip or so and it would click through about four frames. more like a snapshot slideshow.

I want to be able to import video and make simple movies with them. Something similar to Windows Movie Maker (which I have used before.)

Comment: Here is the deal. I can shoot video at 720p and 60fps. When I try to load it so I can edit, make a movie etc., the sound rolls right along, but the video is more like a slideshow of snapshots. This does not occur in 30fps.
I can load, edit, etc., fine on Windows Movie Maker in Win7.
Will the codecs fix this?
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You don't say if in the past you was able to do what you wish (in a different version or distribution). Additionally, it would be useful to know what GPU (graphics card) are you using. It is recommended to have a high performance GPU for high definition video (no matters how long the video playback can be). Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/28078/smooth-fullscreen-1080p-playback/28090#28090 and please inform.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem exactly? You may not have the proper codecs installed, try installing the W32 codecs
`sudo apt-get install w32codecs`
As for the video editor, try Pitivi. It's a very simple video editor, for general use. 
Good luck. :)