# How do I configure mplayer to always use VDPAU?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, mplayer

I just learned how to [use mplayer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53019/how-to-watch-videos-that-have-1080p-using-x264-video-codec-and-ac3-for-audio/63680#63680) to take advantage of VDPAU from the command line with the `-vc ffh264vdpau` switch.

How do I set that config in my `.mplayer/config` file so I don't  have to remember that long flag every time I want to watch a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just put a list of the video outputs and codecs you want to try in your ~/.mplayer/config file? As in:

```
##################
# video settings #
##################

# Specify default video driver (see -vo help for a list).
vo=vdpau


############
# Profiles #
############

# The options declared as part of profiles override global default settings,
# but only take effect when the profile is active.

[vo.vdpau]
vc=ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau,ffh264vdpau,ffodivxvdpau,
# Most video filters do not work with vdpau.
vf-clr=yes
```

<sup>1</sup> the trailing comma in each setting tells mplayer to fall back to standard codecs if necessary