# Command line flag for mplayer to use hardware acceleration?

Tags: command-line, mplayer, vaapi

I can make VLC use hardware decoding with

```
vlc --ffmpeg-hw video.mkv
```

Is there an equivalent flag for mplayer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mind you if you have an nVidia graphics card you should not only specify the `-vo` device but also give a `-vc` setting. On my own system I give the following on the commandline:

```
mplayer -vo vdpau filename
```

(replacing 'filename' with the actual name of *your* file of course) and place the following in `~/.mplayer/config`:

```
[vo.vdpau]
vc=ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau,ffh264vdpau,ffodivxvdpau,
```

but there are several different ways of doing this. This method allows you to use different video out devices with MPlayer but will give proper `-vc` values when you specify `-vo vdpau` from the commandline.

Hope this helps :).

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/63682/how-do-i-configure-mplayer-to-always-use-vdpau

Answer (score 2):

The command is `-vo` (video out).  For my nVidia network card with hardware acceleration, I use `-vo vdpau`.

To see all of the video out processors, see [mplayer.1](http://manpg.es/mplayer.1).