# Laptop battery always discharging

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

I have a fully up to date Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus X550DP laptop. My problem is that the battery is always discharging. When I plug the AC adapter in, it charges battery up to around 96% and stops charging there, but the power management tool says that my battery is in use and is discharging. What is the problem?

Edit( my AC plugged in )

**Ac profile**
[image: AC adapter]

**Battery profile**
[image: Laptop Battery]

Comment: Is battery charge level dropping while connected to AC adapter?

Comment: Have any of the reporters of this problem tried replacing their laptop battery with a new one?

Answer (score 3):

## [Improve Power  Usage / Battery Life In Linux With TLP](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)

### Overview

Use this to improve your battery performance and to maintain temperature. So here is how to install and configure TLP:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

#### ThinkPads

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool

- **tlp-rdw** – Radio Device Wizard - Need to enable/disable & Power saving (Wifi / Bluetooth )
- **smartmontools** - needed by tlp-stat to display disk drive S.M.A.R.T. data
- **ethtool** - needed to disable wake on lan
- **tp-smapi-dkms** ThinkPad only, tp-smapi is needed for battery charge thresholds and ThinkPad specific status output of tlp-stat
- **acpi-call-tools** ThinkPad only, acpi-call is needed for battery charge thresholds on Sandy Bridge and newer models
```

### Configuration

Removing default Ubuntu cpu frequency config

```
 sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

#### TLP Developer

(This is not a general prerequisite for TLP but is only needed **if the user decides** to change the default governor. If a user issues the command **without changing the TLP setting** too, he ends up with "perfomance", which is quite bad for battery life.), Apply to section **3.)** Processor and Frequency Scaling

The main config file of TLP is at /etc/default/tlp

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

### Parameters

**General hints**:

1. Parameters ending on _AC are effective with the power supply connected
2. Parameters ending on _BAT are effective when running on battery
3. Parameters containing blanks must be enclosed in double quotes like this: ""
4. Some parameters are inactive by default; remove the leading '#' to activate

---

0. **General**

   ```
    TLP_ENABLE=1
   ```

   Set to 0 to disable TLP (Reboot needed), It should be enabled so leave the default value
1. **File System**

   ```
    DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
    DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
   ```

   DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2 = You can either leave the default value **(2)** or you can edit it as **5**, By default Ubuntu uses **5**, its up to you, read the gives below help

   ```
    cat /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode
   ```

   This controls how agressive the system is at trying to avoid
   writing to disk.  The longer the disk is idle, the more power you can save.

   This is only active on battery power, and it restores these values
   to kernel defaults when on AC power.

   **Defaults 5**, which enables laptop mode and forces the system to **wait
   5 seconds** whenever something asks to write to disk to flush out as much
   data as we can.
2. **Dirty page values**

   ```
     MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
     MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
   ```

   Leave the default value

   Defaults 60, which means that the kernel will not start forcing process
   to write out file information that has been changed but not saved until 60%
   of usable system memory is filled with dirty information.
3. **Processor and Frequency Scaling**

   CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=ondemand
   CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave

   Remove the hash and edit it as conservative.

   Its up to you what you want, you can also use **ON_BAT=powersave**

   Select a cpu frequency scaling governor: ondemand/powersave/performance/conservative

   **Governor ??**

   The governor decides what frequency should be used.

   Module Description:

   ```
    ondemand        Dynamically switch between CPU(s) available if at 95% cpu load  
    performance     Run the cpu at max frequency  
    conservative    Dynamically switch between CPU(s) available if at 75% load  
    powersave       Run the cpu at the minimum frequency
   ```

   **TLP Developer**

   To use "conservative" over "powersave – especially on AC – should not be
   a general recommendation but only an option for hardware that produces
   excessive heat or fan noise.
4. **Min/Max frequency**

   ```
    #CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_AC=0
    #CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=0
    #CPU_SCALING_MIN_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
    #CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=0
   ```

   Set the min/max frequency available for the scaling governor.
   Possible values strongly depend on your cpu. For available frequencies see
   tlp-stat output, Section "+++ Processor".

   **Hint**: Parameters are disabled by default, remove the leading # to enable them,
   otherwise kernel default values are used.
5. **Turbo Boost**

   ```
    CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
    CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
   ```

   Set the cpu "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable / 1=allow ,Requires an Intel Core i processor and kernel 3.7 or later.

   **Important:**
   This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings, A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it
6. **Cpu Cores/Hyper-Threads**

   ```
    SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
    SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
   ```

   Minimize number of used cpu cores/hyper-threads under light load conditions
7. **Kernel**

   ```
    NMI_WATCHDOG=0

      Activate kernel NMI watchdog timer (0 = disabled/save power, 1=enabled). A value of 1 is relevant for kernel debugging only.
   ```
8. **Hard disk advanced power management level**

   ```
    DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
    DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
   ```

   Set the "Advanced Power Management Level". Possible values range between 1 and 255:

   1 – max power saving / minimum performance

   **Important**: this setting may lead to increased disk drive wear and tear because of excessive read-write head unloading (recognizable from the clicking noises)

   128 – compromise between power saving and wear (TLP standard setting on battery)
   192 – prevents excessive head unloading of some HDDs
   254 – minimum power saving / max performance (TLP standard setting on ac)
   255 – disable APM (not supported by some disk models)

Different values for multiple disks are separated with blanks.

9. **Disk I/O Scheduler**

   ```
    #DISK_IOSCHED="cfq cfq"
   ```

   Select io scheduler for the disk devices: noop/deadline/cfq (Default: cfq)
   Separate values for multiple devices with spaces.

   **noop** is often the best choice for memory-backed block devices (e.g. ramdisks) and other non-rotational media (flash) where trying to reschedule I/O is a waste of resources

   **deadline** is a lightweight scheduler which tries to put a hard limit on latency

   **cfq** tries to maintain system-wide fairness of I/O bandwidth
10. **SATA aggressive link power management** (ALPM):

    ```
    min_power/medium_power/max_performance

    SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
    SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
    ```

    **ALPM**
    Aggressive Link Power Management (ALPM) is a mechanism where a SATA AHCI controller can put the SATA link that connects to the disk into a very low power mode during periods of zero I/O activity and into an active power state when work needs to be done. Tests show that this can save around 0.5-1.5 Watts of power on a typical system. (For more check **" Sources and additional help "** )
11. **PCI Express Active State Power Management** (PCIe ASPM):

    (default/performance/powersave )

    **Hint:** needs kernel boot option pcie_aspm=force on some machines

    PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
    PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
12. **Radeon graphics clock speed**

    (profile method): low/mid/high/auto/default

    auto = mid on BAT, high on AC; default = use hardware defaults (Kernel >= 2.6.35 only, not with fglrx driver!)

    ```
    #RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
    #RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
    ```
13. **WiFi power saving mode**

    1=disable/5=enable

    (Linux 2.6.32 and later, some adapters only!)

    ```
    WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
    WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
    ```
14. **Disable wake on lan**

    Y = Yes , N = No

    ```
    WOL_DISABLE=Y
    ```
15. **Audio power saving for Intel HDA**

    Enable audio power saving for Intel HDA, AC97 devices (timeout in secs). A value of 0 disables / >=1 enables power save.

    ```
    SOUND_POWER_SAVE=1
    ```

    Disable controller too (HDA only): Y/N

    ```
    SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
    ```
16. **Power off optical drive in UltraBay** >> **(ThinkPads only)**

    Set to 1 to power off optical drive in UltraBay (ThinkPads only), when running on battery. A value of 0 disables this Feature (Default). Drive can be powered on again by releasing (and reinserting) the eject lever or by pressing the disc eject button on newer models. **Note**: an UltraBay hard disk is never powered off.

    ```
    BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=1
    ```

    Optical drive device to power off (default sr0)

    ```
    BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
    ```
17. **Runtime Power Management for pci(e) bus devices**

    ```
    RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
    RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
    ```

    **Rntime PM for *all* pci(e) bus devices**

    ```
    RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
    ```

    Runtime PM for *all* pci(e) bus devices: 0=disable / 1=enable, Warning: experimental option, could cause system instabilities

    Some times my usb mouse dongle didn't work when i plug it in usb 3 port, work fine when i plug it in usb 2 port, and all my usb 3 devices are working properly no issue.
18. **Usb autosuspend**

    Set to 0 to disable/1 to enable usb autosuspend feature

    ```
     USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
    ```
19. **System Start and Shutdown**

    ```
    RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

    Restores radio device state (builtin bluetooth, wifi, wwan) from previous shutdown on system startup:
    ```

    0 – disable, 1 – enable

    ```
     DEVICES_TO_DISABLE_ON_STARTUP="bluetooth wifi wwan"
    ```

    Disables builtin radio devices upon system start:

    ```
    bluetooth
    wifi – Wireless LAN
    wwan – Wireless Wide Area Network (UMTS)
    ```

    Multiple devices are separated with blanks.

    I have an error that my **Blue tooth** device is not Disabled on start up, so if you face this problem just do the following config

    ```
     sudo nano /etc/rc.local
    ```

    And add the following line before exit 0

    ```
     rfkill block bluetooth
    ```

**Save & Exit & Reboot**

### Working with TLP

After installation TLP will be automatically activated upon system start.

To start it immediately without reboot or to apply changed settings use:

```
  sudo tlp start
```

Use the tlp-stat terminal command to check if TLP is working properly

```
 sudo tlp-stat
```

Check You system temperature

```
 sudo tlp-stat -t
```

Show battery information only:

```
 sudo tlp-stat -b
 sudo tlp-stat --battery
```

Show configuration only:

```
tlp-stat -c
tlp-stat --config
```

Show radio devices switch state only:

```
tlp-stat -r
tlp-stat --rfkill
```

Show temperatures and fan speed only:

```
tlp-stat -t
```

Apply Battery Settings (ignoring the actual power source):

```
sudo tlp bat
```

Apply AC Settings (ignoring the actual power source):

```
sudo tlp ac
```

You can check Which I/O you are using.

```
 sudo tlp-stat  # Check the section +++ Storage Devices
```

#### Trace Mode

To examine suspected problems in TLP more closely, activate trace mode in /etc/default/tlp:

```
 TLP_DEBUG="lock nm path pm rf run sysfs udev usb"
```

Add above mentioned line in the end /etc/default/tlp , The accumulated trace data may be read at any time with

```
 tlp-stat -T
```

Or

```
 grep "tlp" /var/log/debug
```

In case the trace output is missing, you have to modify your rsyslogd configuration. Create the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/90-debug.conf` containing

```
 *.=debug;\
 auth,authpriv.none;\
 news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
```

And restart the daemon

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

### Sources and additional help

- [There is very good support at TLP Website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)
- [Useful Config Link 1](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html)
- [TLP Settings](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)
- [ALPM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementALPM)

## Optional tweaks

### Tweak your CPU frequency with `indicator-cpufreq`

#### Installation

`indicator-cpufreq` will help you change your CPU frequency on the go:

```
 sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Go to *Dash* > search for *Startup* > edit `indicator-cpufreq` add `-f` or copy paste the following command:

```
 indicator-cpufreq -f
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

With the indicator you will be able to monitor your current CPU frequency & can change CPU frequency

#### Changing CPU frequency

Click on indicator

[image: screenshot]

### [PowerSavingTweaks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks) for Intel Graphics

#### Configuration

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1"
```

and run:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Reboot to apply the changes. You do not need other tweaks as they are already added by defaults.

## Additional Advice

### Regularly discharging the battery

Discharge the battery atleast twice a week.

I have been using Dell utility in windows and it shows my battery health to be 94%. I had 76% before because I was not discharging it. Now that I am discharging it twice a week it's at 94% and I get almost 5 hours of battery life.

[@Syzygy](https://askubuntu.com/users/145/syzygy)

[Battery discharges](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html#descBat) Read before discharging the battery

## Update

VA-API (Hardware Acceleration For Intel / AMD GPUs)

### Overview

I have tested VA-API Hardware Acceleration in **Ubuntu 13.04** and it save around 2 to 4 watts of battery and save cpu usage when playing movies, I would recommend it because it has no downside.

#### [About VA-API](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/vaapi)

The main motivation for VA-API (Video Acceleration API) is to enable hardware accelerated video decode/encode at various entry-points (VLD, IDCT, Motion Compensation etc.) for the prevailing coding standards today (MPEG-2, MPEG-4 ASP/H.263, MPEG-4 AVC/H.264, and VC-1/VMW3). Extending XvMC was considered, but due to its original design for MPEG-2 MotionComp only, it made more sense to design an interface from scratch that can fully expose the video decode capabilities in today's GPUs.

Help full Links

- [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-mplayer-with-va-api-hardware.html)
- [Official Intel Drivers are using VA-API](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/2013q1-intel-graphics-stack-release)
- [Support video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API)

### Install Intel / AMD VA-API drivers in Ubuntu

###for Intel GPUs (for Intel HD Graphics as well as G45 and later):

```
 sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
```

###for AMD Radeon GPUs (you also need the proprietary drivers!):

```
 sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver vainfo
```

#### Install MPlayer with VA-API support in Ubuntu

By default, the MPlayer version available in the official Ubuntu repositories doesn't support VA-API, but you can use a PPA which provides custom MPlayer builds with VA-API support.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sander-vangrieken/vaapi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install mplayer-vaapi
```

Now you need to install **smplayer or vlc**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

### OR

```
 sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

### Configuration

#### SMPLAYER

Its in **Option tab** > Preferences, on the Video tab > General Video > Output driver set the video output driver to "vaapi":

[image: screenshot]

#### VLC

Its in Tools > Preferences > Input & Codecs > Enable **Use GPU Accelerated decoding**

[image: screenshot]

Helpful Links

- [How to correctly enable/test VA-API on Intel Sandy Bridge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247911/how-to-correctly-enable-test-va-api-on-intel-sandy-bridge)
- [Command line flag for mplayer to use hardware acceleration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101948/command-line-flag-for-mplayer-to-use-hardware-acceleration/126723#126723)

## UPDATE

### PowerSavingTweaks for Intel Graphics

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1"
```

and run:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

Added 2 new options

1 = pcie_aspm=force , 2 = i915.semaphores=1

As the test results shows it save around 0.75 to 1 watts of battery

### Before

> Summary:
> 9.40 Watts on Average

### After

Summary:

8.56 Watts on Average

I will try to update more test results, This update is still in **beta process**, i have tested **only twice**, please **share your results** also.

Helpful Links

[3x+ battery life](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134109)

If you google **i915.semaphores=1** & **i915.semaphores=1 battery save** you will find very good links

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have the problem? You may try to recalibrate your battery. Just follow the steps described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/172271/how-to-calibrate-your-laptops-battery-for-accurate-battery-life-estimates/) under the paragraph "How to Manually Calibrate a Battery". The process itself works equal with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

An inaccurate gauge can lead to the fact that the the battery capacity values are are wrong. The battery may report that it still has 10% of capacity when in fact it has a much lower value, and this causes the computer to shutdown unexpectedly.The most adequate method to do a full discharge (100% to a minimum of 3%) consists of the following procedure:

Fully charge the battery to its maximum capacity (100%);
    Let the battery "rest" fully charged for 2 hours or more in order to cool down from the charging process. You may use the computer normally within this period;
    Unplug the power cord and set the computer to hibernate automatically at 5% . If you cannot select 5%, then you should use the minimum value allowed, but never below 5%;

Leave the computer discharging, non-stop, until it hibernates itself. You may use the computer normally within this period;
    When the computer shuts down completely, let it stay in the hibernation state for 5 hours or even more;
    Then plug the computer to the A/C power to perform a full charge non-stop until its maximum capacity (100%). You may use the computer normally within this period.

After the calibration process, the reported wear level is usually higher than before. This is natural, since it now reports the true current capacity that the battery has to hold charge. Lithium Ion batteries have a limit amount of discharge cycles (generally 200 to 300 cycles) and they will retain less capacity over time.

Many people tend to think "If calibrating gives higher wear level, then it's a bad thing". This is wrong, because like said, the calibration is meant to have your battery report the true capacity it can hold, and it's meant to avoid surprises like, for example, being in the middle of a presentation and suddenly the computer shuts down at 30% of charge.
**SOURCE:**[batterycare](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html)