# HD Video Peformance Unacceptable

Tags: 12.04, ati, vlc, hd-video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smooth fullscreen 1080p playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28078/smooth-fullscreen-1080p-playback)

Was wondering if anyone could help me boost HD 1080p video performance on my machine? I've got an AMD Athlon X2 Dual Core processor, 2 gb RAM & an ATI Radeon 5450 video card. I've installed the latest ATI Catalyst drivers, I installed the hardware acceleration things and linked them (I believe) to VLC. Still, it's still not running as well as I would like. Any thoughts or suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also consider increasing RAM and CPU. Full 1080p video performance is a high demanding task for both RAM and CPU and your equipment is having the "minimum requirements". You may wish to take a look at the answers provided in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28078/smooth-fullscreen-1080p-playback. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling hardware acceleration in mplayer, follow this tutorial:

[Mplayer with hardware acceleration in Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-mplayer-with-va-api-hardware.html)